# ntree parameter in predict.gbm

Tags: r, boosting

What is the use of the ntrees paramater in the predict function for gbm models in R ?

When we fit a gbm model, we have already specified the number of trees and the model has been produced accordingly. Is it that the predict function can choose in the model produced at which level of number of trees it should be used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good use of that parameter is **saving time on hyperparameter tuning**. Suppose you want to tune the model on number of trees with a test data set. And you want to try from 1000 to 5000 trees, step by 1000.

Instead of building 5 models, you can just build one model with 5000 tree, and use this ntree parameter to see the performance on 1000 to 4000 trees!

Comment: +1 that's what I'm doing, but are you sure that generating predictions (1) using the intermediate output of a model with more trees via the `n.trees` parameter is the same as (2) using the final output of a model with exactly `n.trees` trees? In my experiments, (1) gives better performance on test set (training set is the same for (1) and (2) ).

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> predict.gbm produces predicted values for each observation in newdata
>   using the the first n.trees iterations of the boosting sequence. If
>   n.trees is a vector than the result is a matrix with each column
>   representing the predictions from gbm models with n.trees[1]
>   iterations, n.trees[2] iterations, and so on.

Since GBM trains the models in serial, you can tell `gbm.predict` to only use the first `n.trees` number of trees. Or you can tell it to give you the predictions from multiple numbers of `n.trees`. I assume you can use this to look at questions like, "After how many trees do my predictions level-off in their accuracy?"

This also means that you cannot specify a higher `n.trees` than you did in training the model. If you do, it will give you a warning message and do predictions based on how many `n.trees` you fit the model on. See the code at https://github.com/cran/gbm/blob/master/R/predict.gbm.R#L57-L58:

```
n.trees[n.trees>object$n.trees] <- object$n.trees
warning("Number of trees not specified or exceeded number fit so far. Using ",paste(n.trees,collapse=" "),".")
```

Comment: +1 for the details. But I think the OP is trying to ask why we have this parameter and the practical usage of it. What do you think about my answer?